# How do I fix VS Code Shared Server Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

After getting into the live share for VS Code, which does work, the shared server option does not work. After running "npm run dev", the local host shows up in the "Shared Server" tab in VS Code. After trying to open the Shared Server, the server is just permanently loading. It doesn't even show the tab preview. The Shared Server shows up for the host, but not for any other participant. The connection mode was changed from relay to auto and direct, but it still doesn't work.

[Loading Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYLhd.png)

Comment: Related docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/share-server-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem (in a Vue 3 + Vite project) by configuring the dev server to be exposed to the network. This setting will depend on the dev server you're using, but is often a CLI flag like `--host`. For Vite the setting is [here](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-host).

Answer (score 1):

update the script in your **package.json** file:

```
{
   "dev": "vite --host"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem, make the additional insight more obvious which you contribute beyond existing answers, the relevant advantage which your solution achieves, especially if the difference is so small and non-obvious. Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Consider taking the [tour].